# Error in SendGrid on Heroku cedar stack

Tags: heroku, sendgrid, cedar

when I try to send an email via sendgrid on heroku cedar stack,
I got an following error :

```
ArgumentError (SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name):
```

my settings in /environments/staging.rb are :

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp' }

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port           => "587",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com'
  }
```

My Sendgrid password/username are obtained from Heroku according to [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid)

Does anyone have any suggestion ?

Comment: Have you set RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV to be 'staging' via `heroku` cli?

Comment: Verify you have your SendGrid credentials set via `heroku config`

Comment: yes, I set up RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV to 'staging'. but i cannot send mail..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving your config from `config/enviornments/staging.rb` into `config/initializers/smtp.rb`.  That way you know ActionMailer is configured regardless of the environment you're in.

You should keep delivery specific setting in your environment files:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help! And if you ever need more SendGrid help, feel free to ping our support team.