# Heroku + Sendgrid = Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, actionmailer, sendgrid

I'm trying to get the Heroku Sendgrid add-on working with my Rails app, but keep on getting a connection error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
```

I've looked at the other SO questions relating to this, but the [solution offered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11583287/165673)- to move the ActionMailer config from environment files to an initializer- didn't fix anything for me.

Here's my current setup:

**config/initializers/smtp.rb:**

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options =  { host: 'http://my-app.herokuapp.com/'}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = 'smtp'
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => 'heroku.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work. However, I have added the following lines to /environments/productions.rb to get mine working.

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
          :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
          :port           => '587',
          :authentication => :plain,
          :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
          :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
          :domain         => 'heroku.com'
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'your_domain.com' }
```

And, make sure to set up your SendGrid add-on correctly for your app on Heroku.

You can check to see if SendGrid is configured properly on Heroku:

```
$ heroku config
```

You should see SENDGRID_PASSWORD and SENDGRID_USERNAME.

Comment: Thanks but it's just not happening. I even copied your exact code, re-checked the add on, and confirmed that SENDGRID_PASSWORD and SENDGRID_USERNAME exist. Still getting the connection error.

Comment: So, you are seeing the error on Heroku logs, right? Or are you running this locally?

Comment: thanks, this *did* end up working. One problem w the code I posted above was that `delivery_method = 'smtp'` instead of `delivery_method = :smtp` which *won't* work. There must have been other stuff I was doing wrong but I've spent way too long on this so we'll go with that. Thanks for your help!